# How to merge two queries result in Laravel Nova and display them on the resource table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm trying to merge two queries results in Laravel Nova. I've gone through the documentation but haven't found a solution. Basically, I'd like to merge two queries results and show them in a resource table.

I tried to override the `indexQuery` method but was unable to do so. [reference](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#index-filtering)

```
 public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query){
     $query_1 =  Model::where('some condition')->get();
     $query_2 = Model2::where('some condition')->get();
     //merge both queries result
     $result = $query_1->merge($query_2);
     return $result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, although its a weird way to do this in nova:

```
$query_1 = Model::where('some condition')->get()->toArray();
$query_2 = Model2::where('some condition')->get()->toArray();

$result = collect(array_merge($query_1, $query_2));
```

I prefer that you `dd($result);` before passing it back to the fields to make sure you structure the fields according to your new collection. You can see the results in the network tab.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this in Laravel Nova?

Comment: If you can give more information it would help, share how is Model 1 and Model 2 structured, and what are you trying to do, there are lots of ways to do this better. Are you trying to load a relationship? select? multiple select? multiple relationships?